# mysql error code 1111. invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, query

Tentei utilizar a seguinte consulta na minha base de dados:

```
SELECT MAX(COUNT(DISTINCT c.unique_carrier))
FROM companhia_aerea c, avioes4 a, ponte2 v
WHERE c.unique_carrier = a.UniqueCarrier AND a.TailNumber = v.TailNumb AND V.DepDelay > 0;
```

Esta consulta retorna-me o seguinte erro

> mysql error code 1111. invalid use of group function.

Alguém me sabe dizer como posso contornar este problema? 
A estrutura das tabelas é a seguinte:

```
CompanhiaAerea (unique_carrier PK, descricao); 
Avioes (TailNumber PK, IDModelo FK, IDTipo_licenca FK, unique_carrier FK, IDtipoAviao FK, IDTipo_Motor FK, data_registo, estado, ano); 
Voo (IDvoo PK, codigoCancelamento FK, Tail Number FK, iata_origem FK, iata_destino FK, Datavoo, Hora_partida_real, Hora_partida_prevista, Hora_chegada_real, Hora_chegada_prevista, FlightNum, AtualElapsedTime, TempoVoo, distancia, DepDelay, cancelado)
```

Comment: Qual é a estrutura das 3 tabelas?

Comment: eu tentaria assim:

SELECT MAX(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.unique_carrier) FROM companhia_aerea c, avioes4 a, ponte2 v
WHERE c.unique_carrier = a.UniqueCarrier AND a.TailNumber = v.TailNumb AND V.DepDelay > 0);

Comment: Pra que o MAX, nesse caso?

Comment: A base de dados tem a ver com voos. Pretendo saber qual a companhia aérea (unique_carrier) que regista mais atrasos de partida (DepDelay). Dai o "MAX(COUNT".

Comment: A estrutura das tabelas é a seguinte:     
  CompanhiaAerea(unique_carrier PK, descricao); 

Aviaoes4 (TailNumber PK, IDModelo FK, IDTipo_licenca FK, unique_carrier FK, IDtipoAviao FK, IDTipo_Motor FK, data_registo, estado, ano); 

 Voo (IDvoo PK, codigoCancelamento FK, Tail Number FK, iata_origem FK, iata_destino FK, Datavoo, Hora_partida_real, Hora_partida_prevista, Hora_chegada_real, Hora_chegada_prevista, FlightNum, AtualElapsedTime, TempoVoo, distancia, DepDelay, cancelado)

Comment: @PedroCunha, veja bem: vc está fazendo MAX em cima de COUNT(DISTINCT c.unique_carrier). Isso não agrega nada, pois COUNT vai retornar apenas um número e você está dando MAX nele, ou seja, vai retornar ele mesmo. Pelo seu comentário, o SQL que você precisa é outro. DepDelay é INT?

Comment: Qual é a estrutura completa das 3 tabelas?  Edite a pergunta e poste o código.

Comment: @cantoni DepDelay tem valores numéricos. No caso em que o voo em lugar de atrasar ser antecipado por exemplo 5 minutos o que aparece nos dados é "-5". Não tenho como INT pois possuo 3 milhoes de linhas com o valor NA, para os casos em que não há informação da duração do atraso. Tenho por isso como varchar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada instrução SELECT apenas pode ter uma instrução GROUP BY. Implicitamente a tua query necessita de duas instruções de GROUP BY: a primeira para dar a contagem de voos com atraso, a segunda para dar o máximo da primeira agregação. Daí a mensagem de erro a referir uma incorrecta utilização de uma função de agregação (MAX).

Segundo o comentário, o objectivo é: "Pretendo saber qual a companhia aérea (unique_carrier) que regista mais atrasos de partida (DepDelay)"

A forma de contornar este problema é, por exemplo, usando uma subquery.

```
select unique_carrier
from 
(
    select c.unique_carrier,
           count(v.IDvoo)  NumeroDeVoosAtrasados, 
           sum(v.DepDelay) TempoTotalAtraso
    from CompanhiaAerea c
    inner join Avioes a
       on a.unique_carrier = c.unique_carrier 
    inner join Voos v
       on v.TailNumber = a.TailNumber
    where v.DepDelay > 0              
    group by c.unique_carrier
) atrasos
order by NumeroDeVoosAtrasados desc, TempoTotalAtraso desc -- quando duas companhias aéreas têm o mesmo número de voos com atraso, prioritizar aquela que tem um tempo total de atraso superior
limit 1
```